# Cochran's C test for outlying variance using C.test{GAD}

Tags: r, lm, variance, outliers

I am testing `C.test` function from package `GAD` which performs Cochran's C test for outlying variances. I have this data frame of SO2 measurements on different stations around the city, which has 3 columns: station, day and value.
The problem with this function is that it requires a `lm` object and I don't quite understand how you build one but I just do:

```
> C.test(lm(data = testSO2E1, value ~ estacion))

Cochran test of homogeneity of variances

data:  lm(data = testSO2E1, value ~ estacion)
C = 0.13123, n = 31, k = 10, p-value = 1.066
alternative hypothesis: Group 28079057 has outlying variance
sample estimates:
28079004 28079008 28079017 28079018 28079024 28079035 28079036 28079038 28079040 
 16.8516  16.0559  17.9118  22.5828  30.0516  22.2366  23.6731  27.0452  26.5118 
28079057 
30.6516
```

The obvious problem here (as someone noted in Cross Validated, I already deleted that post) is that I'm obtaining a p-value greater than 1, when it should be impossible. Another problem is that the function is testing for the 28079057 station  for outlying variance when it is not the one with the biggest variance.

If I use the `Cochran.test` function from `outliers` package it works properly:

```
> cochran.test(value~Estacion,testSO2E1)

Cochran test for outlying variance

data:  value ~ Estacion
C = 0.26268, df = 31, k = 10, p-value = 2.285e-06
alternative hypothesis: Group 28079036 has outlying variance
sample estimates:
28079004   28079008   28079017   28079018   28079024   28079035   28079036   28079038   28079040 
4.1032258  5.3784946  3.3118280  1.7913978  0.3118280  8.6064516 13.1397849  9.0258065  0.9569892 
28079057 
3.3956989
```

When I use `C.test` like the example included in its documentation it works properly, I obtain the same results from both functions but I don't know what's different:

```
data(rohlf95)
## rohlf95 has 4 columns (cage, mosquito, measure, wing), we are testing if 
## one group of mosquitos have outlying variance
cg <- as.fixed(rohlf95$cages)
mq <- as.random(rohlf95$mosquito) 
model <- lm(wing ~ cg + mq%in%cg, data = rohlf95)
C.test(model)
```

Am I creating the `lm` object wrong? What do the variables `cg,mq`  do? Do I need something similar for testing the SO2 measurements?

Here is the link to the data I'm testing: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-0fUAdfgHYzUjcyVHhBcl9rWlk

And here the code for the function C.test{GAD}:

```
C.test <-
function (object)
{
    model <- deparse(substitute(object))
    by.factor <- as.factor(1:object$rank)
    n <- length(object$model[,1])/object$rank
    k <- object$rank
    var <- tapply(object$model[,1], rep(1:k, each = n), var)
    int <- interaction(object$model[,-1], lex.order = TRUE)
    f.int <- factor(int, levels = unique(int))
    names(var) <- levels(f.int)
    mean <- tapply(object$model[,1], rep(1:k, each = n), mean)
    C <- max(var)/sum(var)
    group <- names(var)[which(var == max(var))]
    method <- "Cochran test of homogeneity of variances"
    alt <- paste("Group", group, "has outlying variance")
    f <- (1/C - 1)/(k - 1)
    p <- 1 - pf(f, (n - 1) * (k - 1), (n - 1)) * k
    pval <- 1 - p
    result <- list(statistic = c(C = C), parameter = c(n = n, 
                 k = k), alternative = alt, p.value = pval, method = method, 
                 estimate = round(var, 4), mean = mean, var = var, data.names    = model)
    class(result) <- "htest"
    return(result)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look also into the code of cochran.test() or pcochran(), respectively.

The p-value in cochran.test() is calculated as follows:

```
pval <- 1 - pcochran(value, df, k)
```

and the code for pcochran function is

```
function (q, n, k) {
    f <- (1/q - 1)/(k - 1)
    p <- 1 - pf(f, (n - 1) * (k - 1), n - 1) * k
    p[p < 0] <- 0
    p[p > 1] <- 1
    return(p)
}
```

It simply sets the p-values to 0 or 1 when the "calculated p-values" are >1 and <0, which is not done in the GAD package.

Greetings